# Trigger a google script from Zapier

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, zapier

I have written a google script and deployed it as a web app so that it can be triggered by either get or post requests. Here is the script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inputs (Zapier)");
  
  sheet.deleteRows(2, 50);
}

function doPost(e) {
  myFunction();
  
  Logger.log("I just ran");
}


function doGet(e) {
  myFunction();
  
  Logger.log("I ran as a get request");
}
```

When I use the web app URL to make a get request through my browser it works fine as I am logged in to my google account.

What I want to do is make a get/post request through Zapier's webhooks app which trigger the script.

Every time I try I get authentication errors. I have tried setting up an API key and appending ?key={key} to the end of the web app url with no luck.

Any thoughts on how to fix this or achieve the same goal, i.e. use zapier to trigger an app script?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED.

For anyone experiencing similar issues. I needed to publish as a web app that ran as 'me' every time and allow "Anyone" access to the web app. I previously published where the script ran as the person running the script.

Comment: Can you share how did you publish your sheet? How can Zapier trigger "doPost"?